# Cross domain ajax request to a json file using JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I want to access a JSON file which is in domain1 (example.com) from domain2 (example2.com). For example,

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: 'http://example.com/vigneshmoha.json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            console.log('Status code: 404');
        }
    }
});
```

I want to make this ajax request to example.com from some other domain (ie) example2.com.

I have tried JSONP. I couldn't understand how it works. Can someone please explain the way its work?

Comment: Does the domain serving the JSON actually support JSONP? (Or is it your domain so you can _make_ it support JSONP?)

Comment: It's my domain only. How can i make it support jsonp?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have the patience to write a tutorial from scratch when there are any number of "how to implement jsonp" tutorials already out there on the web. (E.g., [here's one](http://devlicio.us/blogs/scott_seely/archive/2010/09/07/how-jsonp-works-and-some-bits-about-implementing-it-in-wcf.aspx).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your service has to return jsonp, which is basically javascript code.
You need to supply a callback function to the service from your ajax request, and what is returned is the function call.

Below is a working example.

ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            type:"GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async:false,
            url: "http://<your service url here>/HelloWorld?callback=?",
            data: {projectID:1},
            dataType: "jsonp",                
            jsonpCallback: 'fnsuccesscallback'
        });
```

server side code returning jsonp (c#):

```
public void HelloWorld(int projectID,string callback)
    {

        String s = "Hello World !!";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        sb.Append(callback + "(");
        sb.Append(js.Serialize(s));
        sb.Append(");");
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Context.Response.End();
    }
```

Refer [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/2067584#2067584).

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot. Following link contains my snippet using jquery and php. [http://pastebin.com/kWnWVXDh]

Comment: hey @Saranya, can u share any link complete demo! it will be really helpful! plz

Comment: hey @Saranya , how about the post json-p, could you elaborate more about it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling it as:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/vigneshmoha.json?callback=foo', null, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
});
```

And see what happens?