# ASMX cross-domain call (REST vs JSONP)

Tags: jquery, rest, cross-domain, jsonp, asmx

I am new to this stuff, and I have no idea what that is.. Searching from Google make me more confused.

I have .asmx web-service and .aspx web-page to consume the web-service.
Now I want to change the web-service to do cross-domain call (using jQuery?)
I found that there are two ways? ReST and JSONP?
what is the difference between them?

As you can see, I am soooo confused.. any great article, explanation would be much appreciated!!

My web-service is simply returning a 'list' from database and I want to show that list as either XML or JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consume services across domains using ajax - you have the options JSONP or CORS

JSONP is JSON with padding. The server basically returns a javascript. JSONP has some disadvantges like it is subject to XSS attacks, and second, it supports only HTTP GET requests

example:

[Cross domain ajax request to a json file using JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489976/cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-jsonp/19491482#19491482)

For more details, refer [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/2067584#2067584)

You can also use CORS for modern browsers, where the server adds additional headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin to indicate which are the origin allowed to access the service. Refer [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Also refer the wiki page for more techniques to circumvent same origin policy [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

REST is a way of sending and receiving data between client and server , and it will not help in cross domain calls AFAIK.