# Cross Domain From Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cross-domain

I have to make a request from javascript that is on server A, to a php file that is on server B. I can access both servers.

But something is getting wrong. I always get ready state 0, status 0.

This is the latest thing I tried: Please advice what I'm doing wrong. thanks.

**Server A:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://server_B/request.php',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
        alert("Successful");
        console.log("Response completed");
        console.log("resp is" + resp);
    },
    error: function (xhr, error) {
        console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        alert("Error occurred.");
    }
});
```

**Server B: *request.php***

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

    # do the work and save it on $result array.
    print json_encode($result,true);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsnop, and I don't get any result on console so to understand what is happening..

Comment: in your ajax call, use `dataType: 'jsonp'` - learn about [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Do you get a _SecurityError_ from the _XMLHttpRequest_ logged in your console? Does it work if you allow `*`?

Comment: What are you seeing in the console?  What specific request is being sent?  Is it an OPTIONS, or a GET?

Comment: You should have an error in your javascript console. In Chrome (and maybe others, but Chrome for sure), it will tell you exactly what the problem was.

Comment: I see this: readyState: 0
status: 0

responseText:, I also see the php url on red, I'm using firefox.

Comment: Try Chrome... the console gives an error like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://serverB/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://serverA' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @JasonP, The console is giving same as firefox, however I noticed this under networks: GET
(canceled)
jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
Script
0 B
0 B
Pending

Answer (score -1):

To use ajax between two different domains you will have to use [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

You can find more help in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489976/cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-jsonp)

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment. But, `to each his own`

Comment: "_you will have to use jsonp"_ - No, you can also use CORS, which is what the OP is attempting to do.