# How to externalize json-ld and include in html doc

Tags: html, json, json-ld

Is it possible to externalize json-ld and include it in an html document like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/data123.jsonld"></script>
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this online....

Comment: Are you going to use the contents of the `json-ld` document inside the html document or not?

Comment: @mako I'm also curious about this. Did you find an answer please?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can't do that. You should get the **json** with an **AJAX** request.

You can do it easy with **jQuery**

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("data123.jsonld", function(data) {
      $('.json').text(data);   
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="json"></div>
```

If your json file is not in your file system (**cross domain**) you should try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489976/cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-jsonp).

Comment: If you need it for SEO reasons, this sound like a very bad idea.

Comment: @SebastienC. There lot of things that are bad ideas to reach better results with SEO. But SEO was not part of this topic.