# Does JSON-LD have to be embedded?

Tags: html, google-search, json-ld

We are currently using the Microdata format to expose data to search engines and we are looking at exposing more info to be able to support some more advanced Google Search features. As I'm working my way through the fields I'm finding I need information that we currently load asynchronously so it is not a part of the initial response.

JSON-LD looks like its what Google prefers but all the examples I've seen have it embedded in the page. Could you have a link to a JS file so it gets loaded as a separate call? Something like

```html
<script type="application/ld+json" src="/myid123/jsonld.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to externalize json-ld and include in html doc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892397/how-to-externalize-json-ld-and-include-in-html-doc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) as data block, "the `src` attribute must not be specified".

If the `script` element is *not* used as data block, it has to be "used to include dynamic scripts". But a JSON-LD document is not a dynamic script.

For linking to another resource, just like you do it with external stylesheets or Favicons, you can use the `link` element in the `head` (or the corresponding HTTP header):

```html
<link href="/myid123/jsonld.js" rel="alternate" type="application/ld+json" />
```

In principle, consumers could follow this reference (possibly only if a certain [link type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450872/1591669) is specified), and make use of data, just like they do it with embedded JSON-LD, Microdata, or RDFa.

However, consumers don’t *have* to do this, of course, and many probably don’t.
Google Search in particular does not claim to support it for consuming Schema.org in the JSON-LD format. However, they claim to [support "dynamically injected" JSON-LD data blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29066759/1591669).

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error, link is what i meant. but if google supports dynamically loading via JS then this will work as well. Does google need some sort of indication to expect JSON-LD to be loaded dynamically?

Comment: What does this mean? Does Google crawl my json-ld which is referenced by <link href="/myid123/jsonld.js" type="application/ld+json" />? Or do I need to embeed it inline in my <script>-tag?

Comment: @nimo23: According to their documentation, they only support JSON-LD in `script`, not via `link`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892397/how-to-externalize-json-ld-and-include-in-html-doc#, I have to use a script tag and put it inline. Unfortunately, even "@context" does not work with google search..

Comment: It's a pity that google doesn't yet support external JSON-LD document because we need to make the page bigger only to help the search engine; the user doesn't care that there is something hidden in the page as he/she loot at it.

Comment: It's 2024...does ld+json still need to be embedded in a <script> tag or can we reference a linked document using the <link> tag? How ironic if linked documents cannot be a link.