# Google Sitelinks search box JSON-LD script

Tags: google-rich-snippets, json-ld

In order to have a Google Sitelinks Search Box for your website, you have to include this script in your page:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

My question is:
Can `<script type="application/ld+json">` be external? It is obviously useless for page it self and crawlers can make extra request if they want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JSON-LD have to be embedded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864619/does-json-ld-have-to-be-embedded)

Answer (score 0):

While it can't be external in the traditional sense (using the `src` attribute), [it can be injected by JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org).