# Cross Domain Ajax call to get static Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make cross domain call to get some HTML , I am getting below error please some one can help me what need to be done. below is error which i am getting.

**"Error" :** 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://test.com/webclient/widget/GetPromotionalBanner/%7bA301A86A-87CB-4F49-BF0E-A8EE355295BD%7d/Bright. (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-origin' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

Always going on error section.

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
(function ($) {
'use strict';
//==================================================
// DOCUMENT READY 
//--------------------------------------------------
function mytest(ss){
    console.log(ss);
}
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url:"http://mytesturl.com",
    cache: "false",
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers':'X-Custom-Header','Access-Control-Request-Method':"GET"},
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function(html) {
        alert("Cross Domain Call Success");
        console.log(html);
    },
    error:function(error){
        alert("Error Response :", error);
        console.log(error);
    }
});

//--------------------------------------------------
// end DOCUMENT READY...
//==================================================
}(jQuery));
```

> **Respone Header of Ajax call**

Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
Cache-Control   private
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length  886
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Date Mon, 18 Jul 2016 07:46:49 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=pe1r0iiklzj5ch3fuanhzlun; path=/; HttpOnly
SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=a874641e69b948898f6dcb596a987fbc|False; expires=Sat, 18-Jul-2026 07:46:49  GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 5.2
X-Powered-By ASP.NET

**Request Header** 
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He... access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Me... GET
Cache-Control max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host test.com
Origin  null
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0

Comment: Basically all you need to know is in the error message. As you probably have no control over the sever, you should look for a different way to host that html.

Comment: Return `jsonp` data from server. And call Ajax with `dataType: "jsonp"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489976/cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

this header must be set on the server, not in AJAX request.

Comment: I already set the header on server side.

Comment: try setting this header on the server 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,*'